# Separable monads do not induce separable monoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, monads, separable-algebras

Let us first recall the categorical notion of monad: if we have a category $\mathcal{C}$ then a monad on it consists in an endofunctor $\mathbb{A}\colon \mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ together with natural transformations $\mu \colon \mathbb{A}\circ \mathbb{A} \Rightarrow \mathbb{A}$ and $\eta \colon \text{Id}_{\mathcal{C}} \Rightarrow \mathbb{A}$ which must satisfy the usual associativity and unitality conditions, exactly like for monoids in a monoidal category.

An classical way to produce monads is to consider adjunctions: if we have $F\colon \mathcal{C} \leftrightarrows \mathcal{D}: U$ where $F$ is the left adjoint then $\mathbb{A}=UF$ is promptly verified to be a monad with structure maps provided by the unit and counit of the adjunction.

Moreover, a monad $\mathbb{A}$ is said separable if $\mu$ has a bilinear section, that is there exists $\sigma \colon \mathbb{A} \Rightarrow \mathbb{A}\circ \mathbb{A}$ satisfying the equations $\mu \sigma=\text{Id}$ and $\mu\mathbb{A} \circ \mathbb{A}\sigma=\sigma \mu =\mathbb{A}\mu \circ \sigma \mathbb{A}$. Again the idea is to repeat the same definition we have for seperable monoids.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a monoidal category and $A$ is a monoid we can define the monad $\mathbb{A}=A\otimes -$, I read that ensuring this monad is separable does not imply that $A$ is separable.

But if $\sigma$ is the section ensuring separability of $\mathbb{A}$ then evaluating it at the tensor unit $1$ we obtain a morphism $\sigma_{1}\colon A\rightarrow A \otimes A$ which satisfies all the required equations, so $A$ has a structure of separable monoid.
I think the problem is that this morphism does not recover the monadic structure, i.e. for a general object $c \in \mathcal{C}$ it is not necessarily true that $\sigma_c=\sigma_1 \otimes c$.

My question is the following: can you provide a concrete example where the monad $\mathbb{A}=A\otimes -$ is separable but the induced separability of $A$ does not recover the section for $\mathbb{A}$?

Comment: I think this is the same kind of thing as in the case of dualizability: asking that $x\otimes -$ has a right adjoint of the form $y\otimes -$ is not enough to ensure dualizability. Of course this does not help with coming up with a counterexample, but it's worth mentioning; maybe the examples will look similar